# Efficiently sum up a couple of values into several bins in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following script:

```
values = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) # ndarray with some values, of length n = 6
target = np.array([1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2], dtype = int) # indices, of length n = 6
sums = np.zeros(4) # target to sum up
sums[target] += values
```

I think it's pretty clear what should happen: The values in `value` should be accumulated in `sums` at the index corresponding to `target`.

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected, no surprise though.

**Is there an efficient way to implement it in Numpy?**